# ETL/ data warehouse- how to conform dimensions? (Say 'join' Barack Obama, Barrack Oboma, Barrakkk Obammma into one master?)

Tags: string, comparison, etl, integrity

This seems to be a common ETL/ data integration problem.

You have multiple data sources/ software systems, with either client names, or customer names, or employee names .... and there's certainly no (easy) way to validate or mask input on these. At least, not if your business processes and software do not currently have that capability for an upstream solution. If it wasn't done from the start, it must happen downstream usually.

So you'll end up in a case where maybe 95% of your employee names, say, are accurate across each software/ data source. JakeJohnson is listed as JakeJohnson 5x in each software.

But then you have other pesky problems. Despite business guidelines and practices, you may Rob_Lowe entered in one database, and Rob_Low entered in another, and Rob-Lowe in a third.

The ideal solution is to have a "master list" of names that each have a (surrogate) ID number, (say, Rob Lowe, employee ID 9382938) --- and have a system where (Rob Lowwe) both gets flagged as not existing on the master list (downstream of the actual software) ... but also, for the time being, "connected" to entry Rob Lowe, since it's pretty obvious (based in % character similarity) that these are the same thing.

(the reason for surrogate keys is unrelated but basically if he changes his name to Rob High, the connection would be preserved)

Anyway ... I'm confused as to how to programatically check for "number of similar characters" ... or if this is a complex bag of worms.

I mean, you can't directly compare number positions -- Rob Lowe would be way off from Rob 22 Lowe, even though similarity is actually pretty high.

Comment: Read about data quality tools and string metrics like the Hamming distance or Damerau–Levenshtein distance.

Comment: Thanks. Second one is exactly what I need. First one is interesting but looks like it's for equal length strings only.

Comment: I just gave two examples, but I am not an expert to recommend the best one. There are [many string metrics](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) with various properties.  Some data quality tools contain specialized components for string matching, e.g. http://blog.edgewater.com/2010/01/23/informatica-data-quality-matching-algorithms-eliminate-duplicates-and-reduce-costs-3/.

Comment: Sure -- the best would be great, but 'good enough' would also do, and I think Damearau-Levenshtein (number of typographical errors to reach the other one) logically seems the best for 'sanitizing' inputs that largely differ based on user inputs/ errors. Though maybe not, because people might use nicknames vs. full names, etc ... but again seems 'good enough'. Thanks!